# PowerShell: compare hash of mirrored directories

Tags: powershell

I mirror a directory to a backup one using RoboCopy.

I want to be able to find files with incorrect hash values or files that only exist in one side.

Here is how I try to achieve this:

1. Calculate hash values of source and destination files/directories and record to two arrays (source/dest)

```
    $srcHash = Get-FileHash "$env:UserProfile\$item\*.*"  
    $dstHash = Get-FileHash "H:\Backup\$item\*.*"
```

2. Find differences between both arrays and list differing files

```
    Compare-Object $srcHash $dstHash | ForEach-Object { $_.InputObject }
```

3. Aim of above is to also catch files that exist in one side only

When I manually plant a file in the source directory to test this, the Compare-Object line lists a single file but it's the wrong one. How can I make sure I find the correct files? Thanks in advance!

Comment: you may want to look into this >>> New-FileCatalog — https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Security/New-FileCatalog?view=powershell-5.1 <<< it looks like it is designed for what you are doing ... [*grin*]

Comment: Interesting but I don't think it can list differing files

Comment: it looks like you can compare with `Test-FileCatalog`, but i have never tried it. [*blush*]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $srchash -DifferenceObject $dsthash -property InputObject
```

Comment: Thanks but this only gives me the arrows

Answer (score 0):

You can even use select-object

```
Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $srcHash -DifferenceObject $dstHash | Select-Object -ExpandProperty InputObject
```

Comment: Thanks but this give me the same result I'm already getting (wrong file returned)